# What is the encoding for the character č for a MYSQL3 database?

Tags: mysql, encoding, character, letter

I have here an old MySQL3 database with an encoding problem. Since the system should be replaced I need a fix. I have to input the character č. But what is the encoding for that? For

ä -> Ã¤
ö -> Ã¶
ü -> Ã¼

But I need a calculator/map for the [letter č](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x010D/index.html).

The MySQL database is 3.23.49

Edit:

I think the reason is that phpMyAdmin - 2.8.0.3 is used. This version uses

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: Are you manually writing out component bytes of Unicode characters? Yuk!

Comment: No. I have existing entries like BÃ–V and I want input  something like that (phpmyadmin, normal edit in field). But I need the encoding for the characters.

Comment: How can I find the right component byte?

Comment: I can hardly make any sense out of this question. The encoding of a character does not depend on the database engine, it depends on the character set you want it encoded as. Encoding is not a universal attribute.

Comment: The sense is the following: If I input into phpmyadmin "Ã¤" I get a working solution. If I input e.g. &auml; I get &auml; in the text which is not desired. The system is built like that and at the moment it doesn't matter why it is like that. The system should run and nothing else. Soon the system will be replaced by another where such things like encoding have to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use either [`ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;` or `ALTER TABLE t MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;` or `ALTER TABLE tbl_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET charset_name;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html#id760415)

Your way to ask the question makes it very clear that you have some major misunderstandings about string encodings and the relationship between strings and bytes.

It looks to me like you want an UTF-8 character, but instead of asking which bytes that maps to, which is easy to figure out in any programming language or by knowing how UTF-8 works, you ask how that maps to characters in some one-byte fixed-width encoding, probably ISO-8859-1.

Comment: In the meantime I updated my question, because the MySQL database is version 3. You are right if you say that I haven't dealed much with the UTF8 encoding. But I'm also not aware if it is possible to use UTF8 in a MySQL v.3 database without problems. I don't know which scripts have to be rewritten if it is possible to change the encoding. Since my job is to get the character in the system and not to change the whole system I looked after a quick and dirty solution. My question was not to how to change the system, because this will happen soon.

Comment: Perhaps you explain the relationship from where symbols like "Ã¶" are coming from. What I think: The symbols are encoded in UTF-8 but represented as ISO-8859-1. In the database the entry is saved as ISO-8859-1, but the output on from a PHP-script takes the UTF-8 coding? So your solution would be to change the table to UTF-8 to see the entries as UTF-8. But what are the impacts of this on the PHP-scripts and so on? Or is only the output of phpmyadmin showing me the entries in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: It's quite possible that your data is stored correctly in the database as UTF-8, but that the tool which you are using to look at the data is assuming ISO-8859-1. "ö" is represented in UTF-8 as the two bytes 0xC3 0xB6. If you interpret those bytes as if they represented characters encoded in ISO-8859-1, you get "Ã¶".

Comment: The point is, if you tell the database and your tools that you're working with UTF-8, you won't have to convert characters to bytes manually, they will do it automatically. It seems your tools and possibly your database thinks your data is encoded as ISO-8859-1 when it's obviously encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Also, you really must read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1):

Export your database to an sql file. Doesn't matter if all letters are like Chinese (no offense :)) then use the command below to convert your file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv

Then open your file. You'll see all characters are proper.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use UTF8 General. I've found that it covers most of what you'll ever need.

Comment: You are right. But I need to reorganize a whole system. If I change it there I have to change it on many other sides. At the moment I only need the encoding for the character č. A table/map with a list of such a translation would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:

Ä[008D]

Open Notepad++. Type in your letter (č). Encode in ANSI. It shows only a Ä but if you copy and paste you get the code above (the rectangle is not show, but it contains the values 00AD).

Despite that it still not works, but the question should be answered.